# Can multiple MPI processes read from a single file?

Tags: io, operating-system, mpi

There is one file on disc whose data all the MPI processes of my project must have. One approach is that one single process reads the data and broadcasts it to all of the processes. Another approach may be using MPI I/O but I'm not familiar with that at all. Since the file is quite small and this is done only once at the beginning of each run, I decided to use the easiest approach: each process reads the data directly from disc. And it worked, at least on Linux. I'm slightly worried that maybe it can't be in general assumed that all operating systems allow many processes read simultaneously from one single file.

Answer (score 2):

When you launch a bunch of MPI processes, a typical operating systems treats them simply as a bunch of unrelated processes. So, when they simultaneously open an existing file for reading, it is as if you opened the file several times in a text editor. Whether this is allowed or not depends on whether the program itself opens the file for *exclusive access* or not.

This means that the resulting behaviour is not so much a property of the operating system, rather of your MPI processes. I *think* that when you open a file for reading, the default in most operating systems is *not* to use exclusive access. When you open the file for writing, though, it may already be different.

Answer (score 2):

You might find that every process reading the file stops scaling at some point.  Even though the file is small, imagine if ten thousand or more processes were to read it at the same time.

If you have every process read the file with `MPI_File_read_all` (note the _all), this *collective* call will optimize this case where everyone reads the file.